# Setting the order of WooCommerce products within a loop

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce

I'm displaying all of the products on a client's site with a loop, which you can see below. It's working fine, except the order of the products is not showing up as it would on the shop page.

In the admin under `WooCommerce > Settings > Products > Display`, I've set Default Product Sorting to 'Default Sorting (Custom Ordering + Name)' and changed the order of the products in the admin under Products > Sort Products.

How would I go about getting this loop to use that ordering so my client can order them herself?

Thanks very much!

```
<?php
$params = array('post_type' => 'product');
$wc_query = new WP_Query($params);
if ($wc_query->have_posts()) :
    while ($wc_query->have_posts()) :
        $wc_query->the_post(); ?>

        <div class="service-card">

        <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>

        <?php the_content(); ?>

        <form class="cart" action="<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/checkout" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="quantity">
                <label>Quantity:</label>
                <input type="number" step="1" min="1" max="9" name="quantity" value="1" title="<?php _e('Szt.', 'my-theme'); ?>" class="input-text qty text" size="4">
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="add-to-cart" value="<?php echo esc_attr($product->id); ?>">
            <button type="submit"><?php echo $product->single_add_to_cart_text(); ?></button>
        </form>

        </div>

    <?php endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
    else: ?>
    <p>No Products.</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: **A simple trick**. If you want to reorder your products efficiently, is better to do it with `post date/time` on products pages. This way you can have products ordered in backend and in front end too… you can **change quicker `post date/time`  on products list with quick edit mode** instead of editing individual product pages.

Comment: Thanks for that! I used the Post Types Order plugin to the exact same effect in the end, so that my client had a drag-and-drop interface to use. I won't mark this as answered though, in case someone needs an answer to the specific question asked.